# Is there a way to specify multiple handler classes for an eclipse view?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working on a task in eclipse plugin development. I need to create a view whose content changes based on a flag.

```
if(flag == 1){
// show 1 button in view
}
if(flag == 2){
// show 2 buttons in view
}
```

I don't want to put these conditions inside the handler class of the view. Instead, I want to have two separate classes to handle the separate input to the view.

```
if(flag == 1){
// show view with handler class 1
}
if(flag == 2){
// show view with handler class 2
}
```

Thus can I have multiple handler classes for the view ?

Edit 1: Following is how I define the view in plugin.xml

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
  <view
        category="views"
        class="GitView"
        icon="icons/view/git.png"
        id="GitView"
        name="%git.repository.view.name">
  </view>
</extension>
```

The class "GitView" is the handler class for the view which should implement IViewPart interface.

Comment: This is for 3.1 compatibility mode. But in the plugin.xml, I can only define 1 handler for a view. So, how can I define two handlers for a view and then activate the handler I need based on a flag?

Comment: @greg-449 Please see my edit 1. Thanks.

Comment: No, you can't have multiple classes for the IViewPart.

Comment: Okay. Thanks @greg-449.

Answer (score 0):

Just create two classes with constructors. And make the functions in the new classes.

```
if(flag == 1){
    Class1 object1 = new Class1(Button button1);
    object1.showbutton1();
}
if(flag == 2){
    Class2 object2 = new Class2(Button button2);
    object2.showbutton2();
}
```

And for the new classes is something like this:

```
public class Class1{
    private Button button;

    public Class1(Button buttonparam){
        this.button = buttonparam;
    }

    public void showbutton1(){
        //create your view with button and show it 
    }
}
```